# Refused UK short term student visa

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, study, sri-lankan-citizens

My son is a student of the Aeronautical Technical Institute at Forli in Italy. Every year the school organizes a scholars summer camp in the UK to improve their English. We applied to that summer course for our son and we paid the 890 euro to reserve his position. The agency's name is Euro Master Studio in Italy.

Our nationality is Sri Lankan. But we are living in Italy For more than 10 years and working together at Tremagi SRL in Italy. We have working permits (unlimited).

We submitted our all of documents as told by our agent.
But without permission return to passport. The short time Student Visa was refused.

Can you help me please, find some good solution to get permission enter to this summer camp for our son with his group.

Comment: Sorry, but this is quite hard to understand. Can you post a copy of the letter you received saying the visa was refused, with your personal details blanked out?

Comment: Can you please clarify your son’s residence status in Italy? It’s not 100% clear to me how your work permit is relevant to your son’s UK visa application.

Comment: User has not returned to clarify questions. Putting on hold.